# Trie data structure,Counting the number of words in the trie starting with a particular string given

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

So this is what i've got till now , i have been trying to implement the trie data structure and

```
al=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
d={} #for mapping
for i in range(26):
    d[al[i]]=i       #creating mappings like 'a'=0 ...'z'=25

print(d)

class node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children=[0]*26    #0 would indicate ending
        self.val=None

class trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=node()

    def insert(self,word):
        t=self.root
        for i in word:

            if t.children[d[i]]!=0:
                print('traversing')
                t=t.children[d[i]]
            else:
                #print('here')
                t.children[d[i]]=node()
                t.children[d[i]].val=i;

                t=t.children[d[i]]

    def search(self,word):
        t=self.root
        for i in word:
            if t.children[d[i]]!=0:
                t=t.children[d[i]]
            else:
                return 0

        return 1
```

So this is as far as i have been able to implement trie(if any optimizations are there please do mention it :))
Now my question is that if i have ('Stack' , 'Stackoverflow' ,'Stackover' ,'LOL' ) in my trie and i have been given the string 'Stack' so my answer would be 3 occurrences
so for the above case :
  ->      input : 'Stack'
  ->    Output : 3
Basically i want to know how many instances of the partial string "Stack" are stored in my Trie
i am having trouble implementing it

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are asking but you want to know how many words start with Stack in your trie?

Comment: What is the output you want for the specified input, basically if you want the count of the word Stack whether it occurs as a whole string or as a substring then it depends on u, how u want to implement

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are looking for

Comment: i'm sorry for being so vague ,i've edited the question

Comment: How does your data structure know that both "stack" and "stackoverflow" are words?

Comment: both are stored in the trie (they were inserted before) if that is what you were asking ,although you can also detect  prefixes like "sta" with the search method ,with respect to this code a word would be a node whose children only contain zeros

Comment: So once you insert "stackoverflow" your trie doesn't see "stack" as a word any more. Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks lile this class of implementations is what we in the industry call "broken". It is not really a trie.

Comment: You could be right now that I see it ,it might not be specifically telling that "stack" is a word by it self and just tells that it is a prefix after "stackoverflow" is inserted

Comment: Normally each node of the trie contains some kind of independent indicator of the fact that it represents a separate word and not just a prefix of other words. Could be as simple as a Boolean flag.

Comment: i just did that and my problem was solved ! thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import string
al=list(string.ascii_lowercase)
d={} #for mapping
for i in range(26):
    d[al[i]]=i

print(d)

class node:
    count=0
    def __init__(self):
        self.children=[0]*26
        self.val=None
    def increment(self):                  #this is the change 
        self.count=self.count+1

    def showcount(self):
        return(self.count)


class trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=node()

    def insert(self,word):
        t=self.root
        for i in word:

            if t.children[d[i]]!=0:
                print('traversing')
                t=t.children[d[i]]
                t.increment()
            else:
                #print('here')
                t.children[d[i]]=node()
                t.children[d[i]].val=i;
                print(t.children)
                t=t.children[d[i]]
                print(t.val)
                t.increment()





    def search(self,word):
        t=self.root
        for i in word:
            if t.children[d[i]]!=0:
                t=t.children[d[i]]
            else:
                return 0

        return(1)

    def count(self, word):
        t=self.root
        for i in word:
            if t.children[d[i]] != 0:
                t = t.children[d[i]]
            else:
                 return 0
        print(t.val)
        return(t.showcount())
```

as pointed out i added count in every node and easily counted it 
Thanks for the help !!